# How to Draw This Free Body Diagram on TikZ or PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]This is not a duplicate question of the one titled [Creating a Free Body Diagram in TikZ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXW1U.jpg). I am confused as to how one might draw this specific diagram:

Say we want to describe two masses on a pulley and we want to draw 2 diagrams, 1 for each box. They would look like this:

(down arrow) m1g

string

mass 1 (circle)

(up arrow) T

and:

(down arrow) m2g

string

mass 2 (circle)

(up arrow) T

Here is what I've got so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [draw] (0,2) -- (0,1);
\path (0,2)
    edge [near start, xshift=5pt, "$T$", <-, shorten >=10pt, shorten <=2.5pt] (0,1);
\path (0,1)
    edge [very near end, xshift=5pt, "$m_1g$", ->, shorten <=10pt, shorten >=2.5pt] (0,0);
  \node [circle, fill, radius=2.5pt, label=right:$mass_1$] at (0,1) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you draw it by hand say, scan it and post? I don't quite get your explanation. Also please add a MWE.

Comment: Here is the MWE:

Comment: \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz
\begin{document}



\end{document}

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) and add it to the question please.

Comment: As @HarishKumar said, an MWE is needed. You can edit it into your question by clicking the 'edit' link at the bottom left of your question. Then paste or type your code, highlight it and click the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: I thought `pgfplots` was for graphs?

Comment: I didn't know which was used for what, so I included that too.

Comment: Good :-). Now can you add a sample picture (may be hand drawn) to the question please so that we need not unleash our imagination ;-)

Comment: How did you format the code I put in the body as code? Also, why did you put the name of that article in brackets and what is the [1] for?

Comment: the `{}` button makes a code section and the link button makes a link (using the `[1]` markup). I just highlighted the relevant parts with the mouse and used those buttons.

Comment: Do you really have 2 `\end{tikzpicture}` lines?

Comment: Also, remove the `graphicx` line. `tikz` loads it anyway and you are loading it with clashing options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{scope}
      \draw[<-] (0,0) -- node[right]{$W_{m}$}(0,2)
                node[circle,fill,inner sep=3mm,text=white,anchor=south] (m) {$m$};
      \draw (m.north) -- node[right]{$T \uparrow$} +(0,2);
     \end{scope}
     \begin{scope}[shift={(2cm,-8mm)}]
      \draw[<-] (0,0) -- node[right]{$W_{2m}$}(0,2)
                node[circle,fill,inner sep=6mm,text=white,anchor=south] (m) {$m$};
      \draw (m.north) -- node[right]{$T \uparrow$} +(0,2);
     \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanations:

`scope` forms a group around its contents so that we can perform operations (like shift) on the entire group. Every `node`'s contents are separated from the border by `inner sep` (In other words, the distance between the contents and the border). By adjusting `inner sep` we can make the node bigger or smaller (so as to just enclose the contents). We can `label` a node by `(m)` so that we can use that node's anchors (for ex, `m.north`) later whereas `{m}` is the content of the node. And finally `(m.north) -- +(0,2)` means draw a line fron `m.north` to a point that is `0cm` away horizontally and `2cm` away vertically.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Also, I want to learn what this code does instead of just blindly copying it. A few questions: 

sep=3mm - what does this do?

 \begin{scope} - and this?

(m) - why does this have a place here when you already have {m} right next to it?

(m.north) - Does this have to do with (m)? And later, the +(0,2) plots the next line in relation to the end of the first?

Comment: @user11629 I have added some explanations. Ask for any further clarifications. You can always refer to `pgfmanual` which has lot of examples and well written. To access it, run `texdoc pgfmanual` from command prompt/terminal.

Answer (score 4):

[image: two masses]

Here is the code for one of the two masses shown above. The second is just like the first but with slightly different coordinates and modified labels.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [draw] (0,2) -- (0,1);
    \path (0,2)
        edge [near start, xshift=5pt, "$T$", <-, shorten >=10pt, shorten <=2.5pt] (0,1);
    \path (0,1)
        edge [very near end, xshift=5pt, "$m_1g$", ->, shorten <=10pt, shorten >=2.5pt] (0,0);
      \node [circle, fill, radius=2.5pt, label=right:$mass_1$] at (0,1) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't want to change my documentclass from article to tikz, so I just copy pasted \begin{tikzpicture} ..... \end{tikzpicture}. What is wrong with this? The error given is apparently on line 142: edge [near start, xshift=5pt, "$T$", <-, shorten >=10pt, shorten <=2.5pt] (0,1); but I don't think that if it worked for you this is the issue.

Comment: Did you copy the `\usetikzlibrary` line into your preamble? The document class isn't TiKZ. Just `standalone` is particularly good for typesetting images etc. for posting here or including in another document. It is used for lots of examples on TeX SE. You aren't expected to use it for your actual document.

Comment: @user11629 Sorry. Forgot to ping you. You need the `quotes` library. You'll get an error without it.

Comment: I did copy it, and then it wouldn't let me compile because of that line. Now, when I put in \documentclass[11pt] {article} {standalone}, it didn't compile because of standalone.

Comment: Ignore the `standalone`. You just need `\usetikzlibrary{quotes}` in your preamble after you've done `\usepackage{tikz}`.

Comment: @user11629 I never remember to ping...

Comment: I did, and it did not compile.

Comment: Should I show you exactly what is in my preamble?

Comment: @user11629 Why don't you edit your question showing what you tried exactly?

Comment: @user11629 See my comments above. If I remove the call to `graphicx` and the spurious repeat of `\end{tikzpicture}` the code compiles fine for me.

Comment: Wow! That indeed is spurious! And what a hilarious and fitting use of the word! But, that blasphemy aside, why does graphicx impede the compilation?

Comment: @user11629 It is because `tikz` already loads `graphicx` with conflicting options. So when I try to compile your code with it in, LaTeX complains about an 'option clash'. If you really needed to pass the package options, you could do it but, in this case, you don't and would be better not, so the easiest thing is to just remove the line and let `tikz` load `graphicx` automatically.

Answer (score 2):

A recommended diagram with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot,esvect}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[arrows=->](8,6)
    \rput(3,3){\Circlenode[radius=.5]{m}{$m$}}
    \rput(6,3){\Circlenode[radius=1]{M}{$2m$}}
    \pnode[0,-1](m){w}  \pnode[0,2](m){t}   \pnode[0,-2](M){W}  \pnode[0,2](M){T}
    \ncline{m}{w}   \ncline{m}{t}   \ncline{M}{W}   \ncline{M}{T}
    \uput[-90](w){$\vv*{W}{m}$} \uput[-90](W){$\vv*{W}{2m}$}    \uput[90](t){$\vv{T}$}  \uput[90](T){$\vv{T}$}
    \psaxes[ticks=none](.5,2)(1.5,3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An another possibility which more strict follow left part of the given sketch. Right can be easy to add on the same way ...

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0mm,
every node/.style = {inner sep=2pt}]
\coordinate                     (a)  at (0,0);
\coordinate[below=11mm of a]    (b);
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=3mm, 
      at=(b)]            (c)    {$m$};
    \draw (a) -- (c);
\node[below right=of a]         {$T\uparrow$};
\node[above left =of a]  (d)    {$\downarrow W_m$};
\node[above=of d.north west]    {$\uparrow^+$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```